# Can we reduce multiple joins to same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetNotes
    @ResidentId INT,
    @Type INT = 0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    DECLARE @myTab TABLE
                   (
                       Residentid int NOT NULL,
                       Description nvarchar(max) NULL,
                       CreatedOn DATETIME2(7) NULL,
                       CreatedBy NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
                       NoteTypeId int NULL
                   )

    INSERT INTO @myTab (Residentid, Description, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, NoteTypeId)
        SELECT
            R.Id,
            v.[Description],
            v.[Date],
            v.[CreatedBy],
            v.Col
        FROM 
            Resident R
        LEFT JOIN 
            Invoice AS I ON I.ResidentId = R.Id
        LEFT JOIN 
            ResidentCourse AS RC ON RC.ResidentId = R.Id
        --- LEFT JOIN ON USERS FOR Getting CreatedBy Column ---
        LEFT JOIN 
            USERS AS Ui ON I.CreatedBy = Ui.Id
        LEFT JOIN 
            USERS AS Urc ON rc.CreatedBy = Urc.Id
        LEFT JOIN 
            Resident AS UR ON R.CreatedBy = UR.Id
        CROSS APPLY 
            (VALUES (1, R.CreatedDate, R.Notes, UR.FirstName + ' '+ UR.LastName),
                    (3, I.Date, I.Description, UI.FirstName + ' '+ UI.LastName),
                    (4, RC.Date, RC.Notes, URC.FirstName + ' '+ URC.LastName),
            ) v (Col, [Date], [Description], [CreatedBy])
        WHERE 
            R.Id = @ResidentId
    
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Residentid,
        Description,
        CreatedBy,
        CreatedOn,
        NoteTypeId 
    FROM 
        @myTab
    WHERE 
        Description IS NOT NULL 
        AND CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
        AND (@Type = 0 OR NoteTypeId = @Type)
    ORDER BY 
        CreatedOn DESC
END
```

Result

```
Id       Description CreatedBy       CreatedOn   NoteTypeId   
-------- ---------- ------------------------------------------
1        ASD ASD    John Doe         2020-01-02  1
4        ASD DSS    Terry kal        2020-01-02  3
```

I have a `Note` column in every table and a `CreatedBy` column also so in above stored procedure I am performing a `LEFT JOIN` on the `Users` table for getting the name of that user. Considering I have 8 different tables with `Note` / `Description` columns, right now I have 8 `LEFT JOIN` against the `Users` table to get data.

Is there an optimal solution?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't appear to be joining the same record on more than once, only the same table. So its probably the right way to do it. What is your concern?

Comment: I wanted to know that if I am using a good approach performance wise or not.. perhaps there can be a whole new way for this, just wanted to be confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining `I`, `R` and `RC` to `Users`, you could put each `CreatedBy` in `@MyTab` and join in the second query.

```
DECLARE @myTab TABLE
               (
                   Residentid int NOT NULL,
                   Description nvarchar(max) NULL,
                   CreatedOn DATETIME2(7) NULL,
                   CreatedBy int NULL,
                   NoteTypeId int NULL
               )

INSERT INTO @myTab (Residentid, Description, CreatedOn, CreatedBy, NoteTypeId)
    SELECT
        R.Id,
        v.[Description],
        v.[Date],
        v.[CreatedBy],
        v.Col
    FROM 
        Resident R
    LEFT JOIN 
        Invoice AS I ON I.ResidentId = R.Id
    LEFT JOIN 
        ResidentCourse AS RC ON RC.ResidentId = R.Id
    CROSS APPLY 
        (VALUES (1, R.CreatedDate, R.Notes, UR.CreatedBy ),
                (3, I.Date, I.Description, UI.CreatedBy ),
                (4, RC.Date, RC.Notes, URC.CreatedBy ),
        ) v (Col, [Date], [Description], [CreatedBy])
    WHERE 
        R.Id = @ResidentId

SELECT DISTINCT 
    T.Residentid,
    T.Description,
    U.FirstName + ' ' + U.LastName,
    T.CreatedOn,
    T.NoteTypeId 
FROM 
    @myTab AS T
LEFT JOIN 
    USERS AS U ON T.CreatedBy = U.Id
WHERE 
    Description IS NOT NULL 
    AND CreatedOn IS NOT NULL
    AND (@Type = 0 OR NoteTypeId = @Type)
ORDER BY 
    CreatedOn DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Give this a whirl:

```sql
WITH some_cte AS (
  SELECT 'Resident' AS DataSource
       , Id AS ResidentId
       , Notes AS Description
       , CreatedDate AS CreatedOn
       , CreatedBy AS CreatedByUserId
  FROM   Resident
  WHERE  Notes IS NOT NULL 
  AND    CreatedDate IS NOT NULL
  AND    Id = @ResidentId
  AND    @Type IN (0, 1)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'Invoice' AS DataSource
       , ResidentId
       , Description
       , [Date] AS CreatedOn
       , CreatedBy AS CreatedByUserId
  FROM   Description IS NOT NULL 
  AND    [Date] IS NOT NULL
  AND    ResidentId = @ResidentId
  AND    @Type IN (0, 3)

  UNION ALL

  SELECT 'ResidentCourse' AS DataSource
       , ResidentId
       , Notes AS Description
       , [Date] AS CreatedOn
       , CreatedBy AS CreatedByUserId
  FROM   ResidentCourse
  WHERE  Notes IS NOT NULL 
  AND    [Date] IS NOT NULL
  AND    ResidentId = @ResidentId
  AND    @Type IN (0, 4)
)
SELECT some_cte.DataSource
     , some_cte.ResidentId
     , some_cte.CreatedOn
     , some_cte.Description
     , some_cte.CreatedByUserId
     , Users.FirstName + ' ' + Users.LastName AS CreatedBy
FROM   some_cte
 INNER
  JOIN Users
    ON Users.Id = some_cte.CreatedByUserId
 ORDER
     BY some_cte.CreatedOn DESC
;
```

The join to `Users` is now only performed once, but might be sub-optimal. Should it be a problem you can inline the join to `Users` on each individual query.